# How do I get rid of sensitivity list warning when synthesizing Verilog code?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synthesis

I am getting the warning that:

> One or more signals are missing in the
>   sensitivity list of always block.

```
always@(Address)begin
  ReadData = instructMem[Address];
end
```

How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verilog does not require signal names in the sensitivity list. Use the `@*` syntax to signify that the `always` block should be triggered whenever any of its input signals change:

```
always @* begin 
    ReadData = instructMem[Address]; 
end
```

Comment: if I do that then I can't synthesize it :

WARNING:Xst:2319 - "InstructionMemory.v" line 20: Signal instructMem in initial block is partially initialized. The initialization will be ignored.
ERROR:Xst:902 - "InstructionMemory.v" line 104: Unexpected instructMem event in always block sensitivity list.

Comment: That's a strange way to access a memory, anyways.  Usually you'd end up doing a synchronous operation on the memory address and r/w ports, then take the result from its output port.
That said, I'm not down with the ins and outs of using the memories of FPGAs, if that's what you're at.

Answer (score 1):

Add InstructMem to the sensitivity list.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `ReadData` as a wire instead of a reg and then replace your always block with an assign.

```
assign ReadData = instructMem[Address];
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what the declaration of instructMem looks like. Anyway, ReadData = instructMem[address] is going to result in a multiplexer with address being treated as selection logic and instructMem as data lines of the multiplexer using a typical synthesis tool. You would need to put in instructMem in the sensitivity list since whenever this changes so should ReadData.

I tried Icarus, and you anyway cannot do something like always @(instructMem or address) where instructMem has a declaration like reg [7:0] instructMem [255:0] --> implying memory.

Note: do not try to synthesize Verilog memories this way, typically you are supposed to instantiate memory IPs and connect to their ports. Vendors provide memory models for such purposes.